# trimmed check for null on textarea stopped working

Tags: javascript, jquery

Ok, so I have a weird one.  I have a simple check for a null value on a form.

It worked perfectly well when I had the form livinginside an iframe.   However, when I brought the form to the main page and only had it appear in a modal window (pulled from an external twig), for some reason the check *always* returns null.

Perhaps I need another set of eyes, or there's some inheritance issue I need to be concerned about.

Here's what I have:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#submit-suggestion').click(function() {
        if (!$.trim($('#items_item_eresource_notes').val())){
            alert('You must provide a reason for this revision');
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Here's the generated html from the twig

```
<textarea id="items_item_eresource_notes" name="items_item[eresource_notes]" 
placeholder="Is this a major or minor upgrade, what has changed, etc."></textarea>
```

As mentioned, previously this script lived in an iframe.  It is now in a modal brought in from another twig:

```
 <a class="revision" data-toggle="modal"  data-target="#requestModal" href="{{  path('publisher_suggest_revision', { 'publisher_id': pub_id, 'title_id': title_id }) }}">Suggest a Revision</a>
```

and

```
<div class="modal fade" id="requestModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modalTitle" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" aria-hidden="true" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h2 class="modal-title" id="modalTitle">Suggest Revision</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">

            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

(In case its relevant here's the javascript that brings in the modal window:)

```
$('#requestModal').modal('show').find('.modal-body').load($(this).attr('href'));
```

**Edit:**  the one piece I left out was that the form in the external twig was using the same id as its parent for the notes field, because they were coming from the same formbuilder template.   Solving it involved overriding the template to manually create a new id, changing this:

```
<div id="form-eresource">{{ form_row(form.eresource_notes, { 'attr': { 'placeholder' : 'Is this a major or minor upgrade, what has changed, etc.'}}) }}</div>
```

to this:

```
<div id="form-eresource"><textarea id="eresource-notes" name="items_item[eresource_notes]" placeholder="Is this a major or minor upgrade, what has changed, etc."></textarea></div>
```

Comment: A `null` value is very different than an empty string. Are you selecting the field correctly? Is there actually a single `#items_item_eresource_notes` element in the page?

Comment: Sorry, I misspoke.  I am just trying to make sure that a textarea has something in it before it is submitted.  I have confirmed that this element is unique.  there is only one id with `items_item_eresource_notes`  (there is a form label with the same name, but that's a "for" and not an id)

Comment: oh wait... I'm seeing a conflict.  you have given me a clue

Comment: yup.  It's because there 's another form (not in the same modal) but in the host twig that uses the exact same formbuilder template.  ugh;  broke both checks on that field.  Thanks for the hint

Comment: Just look for the element inside the modal or any other parent instead of looking in the whole document (if you cannot change the `id`s).

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I simply overrode the formbuilder field and created the textarea manually with its own id, and that solved both problems. I edited the question to include what I did.  If you would like to write your solution as the answer, I'll mark it as solved.